# What is the best practice to .gitignore API keys from your commits using Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have my API keys currently sitting in my routes/index.js file of my express app. I'm assuming I have to move the keys to an object in a new file in the parent directory of the app (keys.js), then somehow require that file in my routes/index.js file and add keys.js to .gitignore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always keep private information out of your repo.  Use environment variables for keys and passwords.

```
$ MYKEY=abcdefg node app.js
```

Then in your script

```
var MYKEY = process.env.MYKEY;
```

You can also setup a script to launch your app with your keys in environment variables.

```
#!/bin/bash

export MYKEY=abcdef
node app.js
```